# Removing angled section from edge of board?

Tags: routers, table-saw

I have a 1" thick sheet (maybe plywood or solid wood or MDF) and I would like to cut a section out of the edge. This image shows the board, in green, in cross section:

[image: side view of panels]

The angle is 30/60 degrees. I'm considering trying to find a router bit that can accomplish this, or trying to use a table-saw dado blade at an angle. Are either of these the right approach? Should I be trying something else?

Comment: May I ask what material is the red colored part?

Comment: @MichaelKaras same material as the green colored part.

Comment: Ok, So you are looking to make a glue joint between these pieces.

Comment: No glue. The mechanism for attachment is outside the scope of this question. I'm just looking for how to make the groove.

Answer (score 2):

There are router bits designed to cut exactly that profile, at the standard angles needed to assemble polygonal tubes... the usual name seems to be "bird's mouth edge routing bit". Here is [one example of a kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KZM2APG) with the bit with the desired angles:

Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Can you link to one? I've seen them for half this angle, for routing both boards, but not for the notch shown here in just one board.

Answer (score 1):

A dado blade will work fine. I suggest you run the square side of the stock against the fence for the sake of accuracy. You might want to make a sacrificial throat insert if the tilted blade doesn't fit your normal one.

If you end up using a regular blade, add a tall fence extension, because your first cut will be with your stock upright. You'll want to be careful that the cut doesn't remove any of the width of your stock; otherwise, the piece will dive and your cut will be inaccurate. On the second cut (stock flat on table) be sure to have the offcut fall away, rather than being trapped between the blade and the fence. (Hint: projectile stick plus your soft tissues = bad.)

Comment: I was hoping to use a dado blade twice with the board in the normal orientation, rather than standing it up on edge.

Or just finding a saw that will adjust to 60 degrees.

Comment: Oops, don't know what I was thinking. A dado will work fine with the board on the flat. Will edit answer soon.